# TypeScript optional callback parameter does not match anonymous function passed to it

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, signature

I have a simple problem with my TS callbacks.

I have a function like this

```
...
//inside a class
    //function is supposed to optionally accept any callback function
    refreshConnection(callback?:Function) {
        //do something
        //then call the passed callback with no params
        callback();
    }

...

//in another component, i call this function like so
this.myclass.refreshConnection( () => {
    window.location.reload();
});

//but i get an error saying that the function parameter does not match a signature.

// i also tried callback?: (...args: any[]) => any but nothing.


ERROR in ./src/app/fb_connect.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: /var/www/mysite/frontend/angular2/src/app/fb_connect.component.ts (70,41): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/var/www/mysite/frontend/angular2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:115:15)
    at /var/www/mysite/frontend/angular2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:140:17
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 15:0-51
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
```

Note: (70,41) is the function call for refreshConnection. Commenting it out fixes the problem

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20refreshConnection(callback%3F%3AFunction)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20something%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fthen%20call%20the%20passed%20callback%20with%20no%20params%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callback()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ArefreshConnection(%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20window.location.reload()%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A). Could you try to use that site to reproduce your error, then [edit] your question to add the link?

Comment: Are you using resharper? I get so many incorrect errors like this with resharper... it's ridiculous. I sometimes navigate files with a sea of red.

Comment: I dont use resharper, at least not knowingly. The project is an Angular 2 app, and i compile it using "ng build" tool...which in turn uses webpack. 
I added the error code to the original post. Note: when i comment out the function call, everything works fine. I also tried emptying out the function( having a blank function that does nothing. )

I think the compiler maybe giving me a wrong line number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet [seems to be working](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src='use%20strict'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20refreshConnection(callback%3F%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(callback)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Aobj.refreshConnection(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log('It%20works!')%3B%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A) fine:

```
class MyClass {

    public refreshConnection(callback?: Function) {

        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }
}

let obj = new MyClass();
obj.refreshConnection(() => { console.log('It works!'); });
```