# How to pass interface as an argument and get anonymous call back in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

Here is the code, I am trying to achieve:

```
this._customHttp.httpPostService('app/fetchGridDetails',this.req,new  
  InterfaceName() {
         onEvent(str :string) {
            console.log(str);
         }
    });
```

Comment: Can "no luck" be expressed in a concrete error message?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What purpose is the passed interface supposed to fulfil?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623998/typescript-optional-callback-parameter-does-not-match-anonymous-function-passed ?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript optional callback parameter does not match anonymous function passed to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623998/typescript-optional-callback-parameter-does-not-match-anonymous-function-passed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an interface and not a class, you don't `new` it up. You can just create an object that implements the interface inline:

```
this._customHttp.httpPostService('app/fetchGridDetails', this.req,
    <InterfaceName>{
        onEvent(str: string) {
            console.log(str);
        }
    });
```

You probably won't even need to explicitly write the interface name. If the object has the correct methods on it which are expected by `httpPostService`, TypeScript should compile it:

```
this._customHttp.httpPostService('app/fetchGridDetails', this.req,
    {
        onEvent(str: string) {
            console.log(str);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You So much .It works perfectly .God bless you